# How to add variables to script output?

Tags: bash, scripting

A program to calculate statistics outputs its data in this format

```
Calc_Statistics -input_data
zone|label|non_null_cells|null_cells|min|max|range|mean|mean_of_abs|stddev|variance|coeff_var|sum|sum_abs
1|Category 1|2340|6|0.281038027256727|0.462105994578451|0.181067967321724|0.408569300865444|0.408569300865444|0.0272405706818114|0.000742048691070761|6.66730726564858|956.0521640251|956.0521640251
2|Category 2|1504|11|0.231816699029878|0.428150941850618|0.19633424282074|0.368851480689277|0.368851480689277|0.0237446334053689|0.000563807615555358|6.43745101985139|554.7526269567|554.7526269567
...
...
n
```

I know how to select the values i want with the cut

```
calc_statistics -input_data | cut -f1,2,34 -d'|'
```

and I'll get something like this:

```
zone|label|non_null_cells|null_cells
1|Category 1|2340|6
2|Category 2|1504|11
```

And I want to run it for a collection of inputs,eg:

```
for year in years:
    do 
    for month in months:
       do
       calc_statistics -input_data $year$month_data | cut -f1,2,34 -d'|' >> results.txt
       done
    done
```

but I can how can I add in each line the $year and $month variable so the result will be similar with the following?

```
2000|2|1|Category 1|2340|6
2000|2|2|Category 2|1504|11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Print it separately. `echo` is nicely enough to have an option (`-n`) which makes it skip the ending newline:

```
for year in years:
    do 
    for month in months:
       do
       echo -n "$year|$month|"
       calc_statistics | cut -f1,2,34 -d'|' >> results.txt
       done
    done
```

Alternatively, pass them to `calc_statistics` and make it print them too (then adjust the `cut` call appropriately). Your example is a bit odd, since both `$month` and `$year` are not used at all.

EDIT:
Ah, in that case you could use `paste`, but it's much simpler to do it with text editing apps. In my case `sed`:

```
for year in years:
    do 
    for month in months:
       do
       calc_statistics | cut -f1,2,34 -d'|' | sed "2,$ s/^/$year|$month|/" >> results.txt
       done
    done
```

What it does is read each line after the first (`2,$` signifies the line range) and replaces the beggining of the line (`^`) with the wanted values. All just before saving the string to the results file.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but it doesn't work. THe program gives all the results on one go, so it only prints it in the first line

Comment: Try now, this should be it.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work either. Sed adds the year|month without checking if it exists, first. So after a couple runs the first line reads : 2010|09|2010|08|2010|07|2010|06|2010|05|2009|09|2009|08|2009|07|2009|06|2009|05|2008| and so on...

Comment: I see, you are running it over and over again. Wait a bit.

Comment: Just run it. It works nicely! Thank you again!